# How to save name that is entered in text box and the time that is on the timer when the game is completed

Tags: c#

At the minute i have a match picture game in c# windows forms with a timer that stops when all matches are complete. I am wondering how do i save the time taken and the name that is entered using btn_player in a text file. The text file is stored at (@"E:\Match Picture\Public\Files\playerdetails.txt");

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;

namespace Match_Picture
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string Temp_Tag = "";
    int Number_of_Images = 0;
    Label Clicked_Picture = new Label();
    Label Temp_Pic = new Label();
    int Num_Correct = 0;




    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Picture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Clicked_Picture = (Label)sender;

        Number_of_Images++;



        if (Number_of_Images < 3)
        {
            Clicked_Picture.Text = Clicked_Picture.Tag.ToString();


            if (Number_of_Images == 1)
            {
                Temp_Tag = Clicked_Picture.Tag.ToString();
                Temp_Pic = Clicked_Picture;



            }
            else
            {
                if (Temp_Tag != Clicked_Picture.Tag.ToString())
                {
                    tmr_Delay.Enabled = true;
                    scorecounter.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(scorecounter.Text) - 20);
                }
                else
                {
                    Num_Correct++;
                    scorecounter.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(scorecounter.Text) + 50);
                    lbl_Matches.Text = Num_Correct.ToString();
                    if (Num_Correct == 8)
                    {
                        tmr_1.Stop();
                        MessageBox.Show("Congratulations, all matches complete");
                        MessageBox.Show("Number of seconds to match all the pictures: " + i);


                        this.Close();
                    }
                }
                Number_of_Images = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    private void tmr_Delay_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Clicked_Picture.Text = "R";
        Temp_Pic.Text = "R";

        tmr_Delay.Enabled = false;
    }

    int i = 0;
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        i++;
        lbl_time.Text = i.ToString() ;
    }




    private void btn_player_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: for starters to get the elapsed time you need to calculate the EndTime - the StartTime I you can find many examples of that on line also I thing that you would be better doing your stuff in a While loop for example `While( notMatched){ //do work}` also what is the Interval setup for in the timer and if matched you need to stop the timer as well...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the StreamWriter class in order to do what you need.

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"E:\Match Picture\Public\Files\playerdetails.txt"))
{
    writer.WriteLine("") // This is where you will write what you want to that file     
}
```

As MethodMan, you can use EndTime - StartTime, and any other conversions necessary in order to get it in the format you want (minutes, seconds, etc).

This code will simply write to the text file. It will create it if it does not exists, and it will overwrite the file if it does exist. You need to do the proper checks to make sure that you don't overwrite it, or you can use

```
new StreamWriter(@"E:\Match Picture\Public\Files\playerdetails.txt", true)
```

if you want to append the file instead of overwriting. Full documentation of the StreamWriter class can be found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

As an aside, if you're trying to keep records of high score, you should also look into the `StreamReader` class. You can read in the file into a dictionary of `Player` and `Time`, and check to see if a player already exists in the file and only adjust their score if it beats their best score.